# Creating a clickable search result from a JSON table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have created a key up search function using html,ajax and JSON, and this works fine, it pulls results from the JSON table and displays them.

However, I need a user to be able to click on the search result and proceed to that relevant page. To be more specific, I am making an ecommerce page, the search brings back products for sale. So i need a user to be able to click into the product for sale. The html is below:

```
<div id="searcharea">
  <label for="search">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/search.jpg"></a> 
  </label>
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" />
</div>
<div id="update"></div>
```

next is the script code:

```
<script>
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
        $.getJSON('searchshop.json', function(data){
        var output = '<ul href class="searchresult">';
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if((val.brand.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.type.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output +='<h1>' + val.brand + '</h1>';
                output +='<h2>' + val.product + '</h2>';
                output +='<img src="images/' + val.imageref +'" />';
                output +='<p>' + val.price +  '</p>';

            }
        });
            output += '</ul>';
            $('#update').html(output);
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have code that displays the product, you can just change it so that the display is wrapped by an `<a>` tag, and set the `href` to the relevant page (I would imagine this is part of your database, or can be programmatically generated).

Comment: i need it to link within my website if that makes sense? When the search result with the appropriate products are listed I need to be able to click on these products? Am i still able to do that, Im so confused, thankyou for replying

Comment: Yes, the `<a>` tag would make it clickable; see @Flgor's answer and replace the `href` with where you want the user to go when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you can add some markup to generate links, or make the "item" container clickable.

Example making product name clickable

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
    if((val.brand.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.type.search(myExp) != -1)) {
        output +='<h1>' + val.brand + '</h1>';
        output +='<h2><a href=\"link-to-product\" >' + val.product + '</a></h2>';
        output +='<img src="images/' + val.imageref +'" />';
        output +='<p>' + val.price +  '</p>';

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Im not sure how to go about linking it to the product within my website? Im not very good at this.